# Expose SOAP API using WSDL 1.1 as REST API in WSO2 API Manager 4.1

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I Try to expose my old SOAP Backend which use WSDL version 1.1 as a REST API in WSO2 API Manager but i got this error "Error: response status is 415".

As shown in the attached photo below

[image: Screenshot of error]

Logs found in carbon logs .

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "POST /Amplitude-WS/public?wsdl HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Origin: https://uib-as522.uib.socgen:9443[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "SOAPAction: [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Referer: https://uib-as522.uib.socgen:9443/[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "activityid: 083f1db3-599f-4c90-942c-31d1ed180b58[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: application/soap+xml[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: uib-as150.uib.socgen:9443[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "1ce[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://services.omnichannel.ws.uib.tn.com/"><soapenv:Body><web:BranchList><BranchListRequest><MessageHeader><RequestChannel>string</RequestChannel><InitialRequestId>string</InitialRequestId><RequestTime>string</RequestTime><RequestId>string</RequestId></MessageHeader></BranchListRequest></web:BranchList></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-05 13:00:35,962] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: Any errors in the server logs? During the API creation or during API invocation? Shall we enable wire logs and see?

Comment: @Lakshitha i have updated my question with logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, it looks like your backend is SOAP 1.1. But the SOAP request generated by APIM is SOAP 1.2. To fix this you will need to make the following changes,

1. Change the endpoint format to SOAP 1.1

This setting can be found at API Configurations -> Endpoints -> Click on the gear icon to open the Advanced Configurations UI

[image]

2. Change the messageType and SOAP envelope in Transformation Configurations

This setting can be found at API Configurations -> Resources -> Expand a resource and can see this to the end of it.

Change the messageType property from `application/soap+xml` to `text/xml` as follows,

```xml
<property description="messageProperty" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
```

Change the SOAP Namespace from `https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` to `https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` in the PayloadFactory as follows,

```xml
<payloadFactory description="transform" media-type="xml">
  <format>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      ...
</payloadFactory>
```